# Numpy flip boolean array by index?

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have

```
>>> arr = np.array([True, True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Is it possible to call something like

```
>>> arr.flip_boolean_array_by_index(2)
[True, True, True]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the bitwise-negation operator `~`, or bitwise-xor (`^`) with 1.

```
arr[idx] = ~arr[idx]
```

or

```
arr[idx] ^= 1
```

`idx` can be an index, a slice, a "fancy" index, etc.

Comment: `^= True` might be cleaner.

Comment: I know how to do it in multiple steps. I want to know if there's a utility function that returns it in-place, it would read very nicely.

Comment: @user2357112 I indeed contemplated that. On one hand it is cleaner because we are doing a boolean operation. on the other hand, it is way more common to think about xor'ing bits than xor'ing (logical) boolean values...

Comment: Failing that, though, I'd like to know how to do it with the minimum possible footprint.

Comment: @user3557216 can you please explain exactly what you mean by "steps" and "footprint"? do you mean memory footprint? I consider either of the solutions a single-step...

Comment: @user3557216: There is such a function. I dunno if it reads very nicely, though, and it's a fairly new feature: `numpy.logical_not.at(arr, 2)`.

Comment: or you could just make it nice and easy `arr[idx] = not arr[idx]` ... no need for binary negation ...

Answer (score 0):

I found that `^= 1` on a `dytpe=numpy.bool_` array gave a UFuncTypeError (can't cast from dtype int64 to dtype bool). However, `^= True` works, e.g. `arr[idx] ^= True`. This was in numpy 1.26.3.